# maven spotbugs doesn't generate report

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, spotbugs

I configured maven spotbugs plugin based on docs on its website, but it doesn't generate report.

This was a line I saw when running

```
mvn site -X

> [INFO] 15 reports detected for
> maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.1.0: ci-management, dependencies,
> dependency-info, dependency-management, distribution-management,
> index, issue-management, licenses, mailing-lists, modules,
> plugin-management, plugins, scm, summary, team [DEBUG] ******
> SpotBugsMojo canGenerateReport  
> ******* [DEBUG] canGenerate is false
```

Please watch the last line!

Answer (score 2):

I found out through checking source code that it needs to have classes folder generated in target before being able to run any check.

So right way to run it is

```
mvn compile site
```

Which generates classes in target folder and writes this log to console:

```
> [INFO] 15 reports detected for
> maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.1.0: ci-management, dependencies,
> dependency-info, dependency-management, distribution-management,
> index, issue-management, licenses, mailing-lists, modules,
> plugin-management, plugins, scm, summary, team [DEBUG] ******
> SpotBugsMojo canGenerateReport ******* [DEBUG] canGenerate Src is true
> [DEBUG] ****** SpotBugsMojo executeSpotbugs ******* [DEBUG] ******
> Executing SpotBugsMojo *******
```